# Migrating GXT 2.x to GXT 3.x. What to do for multiselectcombo, models and checkboxlistview

Tags: gxt

After a long time, again i started GXT coding, upgrading old application with new versions of GXT & GWT. When i replaced gxt 3.x jar with 2.x, got so many errors, thought all are related to imports, but most of the panels, layouts, multiselectcombo, models and checkboxlistview not there. Expecting favorable response from members.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find informations about the migration from GXT 2.x to GXT 3.x:

[Migration Guide](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/migration/Migration2to3.html)

Hope that helps.